# Setting different alignments on ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a list view with no columns and i want my 3 Labels to have 3 different horizontal alignments (Left , Center , Right) so when resizing the Window (and ListView resizes too) the the 1st Label should be on the far left side , the 2nd shall be on the Center and the 3rd on the far right side of the item

Here is my XAML attempt

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Content="L1" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80"/>
                <Label Content="L2" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80"/>
                <Label Content="L3" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of the `ListView` to `Stretch` and it should work. (Default is `Left`)
Also, you can place your 3 labels in a `Grid` instead of a `WrapPanel`.

Comment: thank you , the Grid was also required instead of the WrapPanel